# Convert $y^2 = 4(x + 1)$ to a polar equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to convert the rectangular cartesian equation

$$
y^2 = 4(x + 1)
$$

to a polar equation. After replacing $y = r \sin \theta$ and $x = r \cos \theta$, I get

$$
r^2 \sin^2 \theta = 4(r \cos \theta + 1)
$$

After replacing $\sin^2 \theta = 1 - \cos^2 \theta$ and rearranging, I get

$$
r^2 - r^2 \cos^2 \theta - 4r \cos \theta -4 = 0
$$

That's where I'm stuck and I can't solve the equation in terms of $r$.

Comment: It is a second order equation in r. You can find two roots in function of theta

Comment: Language nitpick: you don't mean "I can't seem to express the equation in terms of $r$." Presumably you mean you can't solve for $r$ in terms of $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for the language nitpick, I corrected my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic approach.** Rewrite your equation as

$$
(\sin^2\theta) r^2 - (4\cos\theta) r - 4 = 0
$$

and use the quadratic formula for $r$.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Please change $1$ to $4$.

Comment: Oops, duly noted and corrected.

Answer (score -1):

$$r^2−r^2\cos^2θ−4r\cosθ−4=0$$

$$\implies r^2 = r^2\cos^2θ+4r\cosθ+4$$

**If  $r\cosθ = P$**
, then

$$r^2 = P^2 + 4P + 4$$

$$\implies r^2 = (P+2)^2$$

$$\implies r = P + 2$$Now

$$r = r\cosθ + 2$$

$$\implies r - r\cosθ = 2$$

$$\implies r(1-\cosθ) = 2$$

$$\implies r = 2/(1-\cosθ)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing (and accepted) answer.

Comment: How is this answer the same as the existing answer? I think this constitutes as an alternative approach to the OP's working out.